# JNI: Class not found or FindClass returns NULL

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying JNI with C++. But I get this error: `Class not found!`. I searched other solved, but not working for me.
**Code.java:**

```
package com.xxx;

public class Code
{
  public void getMessage()
  {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  JavaVM* jvm;
  JNIEnv* env;
  JavaVMInitArgs jvm_args;
  JavaVMOption options[1];

  options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=myclasses";
  jvm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
  jvm_args.options = options;
  jvm_args.nOptions = 1;
  jvm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

  jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &jvm_args);
  if (res < 0)
  {
    cout << "Cannot create JVM!\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  jclass class_ = env->FindClass("com/xxx/Code");
  if (class_ == 0)
  {
    cout << "Code class not found!\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  jmethodID method_id = env->GetMethodID(class_, "getMessage", "()V");
  if (method_id == 0)
  {
    cout << "getMessage() method not found!\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  env->CallVoidMethod(class_, method_id);

  return 0;
}
```

**Directory for my files:**
[image: Directory]

I tried `-Djava.class.path=myclasses/com/xxx` and `env->FindClass("Code");`. Also I tried `-Djava.class.path=myclasses` and `env->FindClass("com/xxx/Code");`. But both not working. What is reason of `Code class not found!` message?

Comment: Did you compile Code.java using javac?

Comment: I compiled Code.java with javac. But result is same.

Comment: Are you sure that myclasses is in the working directory when you execute main?

Comment: 'Class not found!' is an error message printed by your program. It contains very little useful information. What you need is the exception that is pending when you get the null return. That will tell you why.

Comment: I checked it, I get this exception: `ClassNotFoundException`. You look at the [output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23719289/).

Comment: Your code assumes that "myclasses" is a folder under the CWD of your C++ program.  While the directory structure looks correct, this won't work unless the CWD is the parent of "myclasses".  Try printing the return of getcwd() and see where you are.

Comment: @Wheezil thanks! It's works. Reason of problem is directory not JNIExample. Qt Creator creates build-JNIExample*** directory. I use `javac Code.java` and I moved the .class file into build-JNIExample***/myclasses/com/xxx directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially put this in a comment, but poster indicates it is the solution.

Your code assumes that "myclasses" is a folder under the CWD of your C++ program. While the directory structure looks correct, this won't work unless the CWD is the parent of "myclasses". Try printing the return of getcwd() and see where you are